# nested structs from json, parsed into structs

Tags: json, go, struct

I have a data set that comes from an api query that gets `json.Unmarshal()` into a struct. Once done with the data. it then needs to be exported with different key names.

I have this so far. While it works, I just want to see if there is a better way.

Struct used to parse the incoming api

```
type Bars struct {
    Link   string `json:"bar_link"`
    Name   string `json:"name"`
}

type Foos struct {
    Foo    string  `json:"foo"`
    Bar    []Bars  `json:"bars"`
}

type Opts struct {
     Something string `json:"something"`
}

type Test struct {
    ID           string        `json:"id"`
    Name         string        `json:"name_from_api"`
    StringDesc   []string      `json:"name_from_api_one"`
    NumberField  int           `json:"name_from_api_two"`
    Foo          []Foos        `json:"foos"`
    Opts         Opts          `json:"option_stuff"`
}
```

Parse incoming data with above struct.

```
var test Test

json.Unmarshal(data, &test)

return test
```

Change the output with another struct, including changing some of the keys:

```
type Bars struct {
    Link   string `json:"different_name_of_link_key"`
    Name   string `json:"name"`
}

type Foos struct {
    Foo    string  `json:"different_foo_name"`
    Bar    []Bars  `json:"bars"`
}

type Opts struct {
     Something string `json:"something"`
}

type Test struct {
  ID                string        `json:"id"`
  Name              string        `json:"different_name"`
  StringDesc        []string      `json:"different_name_two"`
  NumberField       int           `json:"different_name_three"`
  Foo               []Foos        `json:"foos"`
  Opts              Opts          `json:"option_stuff"`
}

// test is "test" returned in the above unmarshal

var foos []Foos
for _, i := range test.Foo {
  var f []Bars
  for _, b := range i.Bar {
    f = append(f, Bars(b))
  }
  foos = append(foos, Foos{
    Foo: i.Foo,
    Bar: f,
  })
}

return {
  ID: test.ID,
  Name: test.Name,
  StringDesc: test.StringDesc,
  NumberField: test.NumberField,
  Foo: foos,
  Opts: Opts(test.Opts),
}
```

Here is most recent playground: https://play.golang.org/p/yoHfzmHfxKp

---

Update: Used convert type for Bars.

Comment: If the structs are the same except the json tags, you can use `Foo(otherFoo)` instead of field-by-field copy.

Comment: I thought that too, but because they are nested structs, i get `cannot conver type` errors.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I do do that with the `Opts` field, and it works beautifully.

Comment: In your playground you can convert type rather than assigning like `f = append(f, OBars(b))` instead `f = append(f, Bars{ Link: b.Link, Name: b.Name, })`

Answer (score 0):

If you are not mutating the data you can do a string or if you wish a regex replace, of your intial string you got. If you are mutating the data , marshal and do the string/regex replacements , so that you do not have to maintain a few extra structs. I however do not know about performance hit if any.